# Question on intuitive understanding of directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Khan Academy's [article](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/directional-derivatives-going-deeper) on the directional derivative is very helpful to me for my understanding. However, there is a section of it that I'm confused about, namely this part:

[image]

It is not apparent to me that Step 3 changes the output of the function by $hv_1\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\right)$, and their article hyperlinked that states to explain it doesn't for me. Does someone know where they're coming from here?

Comment: I don’t know what article is hyperlinked, but the claim in Step 3 is true because the partial derivative in the $x$-direction is the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $x$ at the point $(x_0,y_0)$. If the temperature as you move east increases at a rate of $1.3\, ^\circ C$ per meter, and you move a small distance $hv_1$ meters to the east, you would expect the temperature to increase by about $hv_1\cdot 1.3\, ^\circ C$.

Comment: When you take partial derivatives, you fix all but one variable, so this is nothing but the old familiar $f(x+h)-f(x)\approx hf'(x).$

Comment: @SteveKass This is going to sound stupidly obvious to you I bet so forgive me, but why is the temperature increase $hv_1 * 1.3$ and not $hv_1 + 1.3$?

Comment: Because that’s how rates of change work. The amount of change in $A$, if $B$ changes a little (and $A$ depends on it) equals the rate of change of $A$ with respect to $B$ **times** the change in $B$. If you are driving at a rate of 40 miles per hour, how far do you go in 0.2 hours? The answer is $0.2\times40$, not $0.2+40$.

Comment: Maybe worth adding: Changes add if they happen in succession. If you move East a little bit and then North a little bit, the change in temperature is the change due to your moving East **plus** the change due to your moving North. But the Eastward change in temperature is found by **multiplying** the Eastward rate of change by the Eastward distance moved, and similarly for the Northward part.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the expression$$hv_1\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(x_0,y_0)$$ is a product of two quantities.

The first part is $hv_1$ which is simply the change in $x$.

The second part $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0)$ which is the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $x$.

When we multiply the $x$-increment by the rate of change of the function with respect to $x$, we get the total change of $f$ due to this $x$-increment.